# What does assigning 'shift' to a variable mean?

Tags: perl, variables

Example:

```
use strict;
my $file = shift;

open(IN, $file) || die "Unable to open $file\n";
open(OUT, ">$file.$$") or die $!;
```

What is going on with the `my $file = shift`?

Comment: this is a common Perl idiom, please read [`perldoc perlintro`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Writing-subroutines) for common use of Perl.

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know the difference between `"shift"` and `shift()`?

Comment: Exact duplicate of *[What does shift() do in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296964/what-does-shift-do-in-perl)*.

Answer (score 32):

If used in the main program, it will `shift` (remove and return) the first value from `@ARGV`, the argument list of your program. If used inside a subroutine, it will shift the first value from `@_`, the argument list of the sub. See the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) for more info.

Comment: For local documentation of built-in functions: perldoc -f shift (Ubuntu, at least, will need you to install the perl-doc package for this to work, but tells you so when you try it).

Comment: Forgive me but this seems like the worst convention ever for code readability.

Comment: @CynicalOptimist It is only confusing the first time you see it, unless you have a rather bad memory for details.

Comment: I respect you're opinion, but I have to disagree for the guy who's reading it. For the guy writing it, probably not terrible...

Comment: @CynicalOptimist I think people often are unfair when it comes to Perl. There are precious few languages that you can understand completely without consulting a manual, why would Perl be any different? I don't understand why people think that.

Answer (score 16):

You can read the documentation on `shift`. It is very clear. `shift` accepts an array and extracts the first element (actually removing it from the array). If you don't provide any array, it uses `@ARGV` (the arguments to the command line of the program) to read the data. If you're inside a function, it uses `@_`, namely, the parameters of the function.

Example:

```
my @array = (1, 2, 3);
my $value = shift @array;
print $value; # will print '1'
```

Answer (score 5):

`shift` uses the `@_` variable which contains the values passed to a function or `shift` uses `@ARGV` for the values passed to the script itself if `shift` is referenced outside of a function.

ONE WORD OF CAUTION:  It is probably wise, especially in Windows where many paths contain spaces, to put the filename and path in single quotes when you pass it to the script or function.  This will tell Perl that you are passing it a single scalar value rather than an array of values.  You can use double quotes if you want to interpolate part of the name.  For example:

```
my $path = 'C:\Goat Kids';
func("$path\\goat.txt");
```

Or, from the command line if you are passing the filename directly to the script:

```
perl goat.pl "C:\Goat Kids\goat.txt"
```

Comment: Careful, single quotes don't mean the same thing in a Windows command line as they do in a Unix shell.  If you type `perl goat.pl 'C:\Goat Kids\goat.txt'` in a Windows command shell, `goat.pl` will see an argument with single quotes.

Comment: I corrected it.  Thanks.  I generally do not use command line options because most of my users just want to double-click the script to run it.  However, I write scripts that call functions with filenames as parameters on a very frequent basis.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a question and answer site, not a newsgroup or discussion forum. It works by someone asking a question, and then people can post answers to the question by typing into the "Your Answer" area. Your post is not an answer to the question asked ("I agree the other answers are good"), and should not appear as one. If you haven't already, please take a few minutes to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and a few other questions to see how the site is designed to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The previous answers have described how `shift` works. I would like to comment on why it is a good idea to use it in your own programs.

Perl by default is a pass-by-reference language. If a subroutine modifies its argument, the caller will see these, sometimes unexpected, changes. It is a good practice to use `shift` to assign a subroutine argument to a private variable. This way, if you make any changes to it, it will not be visible to the caller. E.g., the code below outputs

```
1
2
2
```

The first subroutine modifies its argument and the caller sees the change. The second subroutine modifies a private *copy* of its argument, and this change is not visible in the caller.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub pass_by_ref {
    $_[0] = 2;
}

sub pass_by_value {
    my $x = shift @_;
    $x = 3;
}

my $x = 1;
print $x, "\n";
pass_by_ref($x);
print $x, "\n";
pass_by_value($x);
print $x, "\n";
```